# p:treeTable not sending on sub-node

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I use PrimeFaces with a `p:treeTable`:

```
root
  Area
    Equipment 1
    ...
    Equipment n
  Area 2
    Equipment 1
    ...
    Equipment n
```

```java
public TreeNode getRoot() {
    DefaultTreeNode root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
    for (Area area : areas) {
        TreeNode areaNode = new DefaultTreeNode("area", new AreaTreeNode(area), root);
        root.getChildren().add(areaNode);
        for (Equipment e : equipments) {
            TreeNode eNode = new DefaultTreeNode("equipment", new EquipmentTreeNode(e), areaNode);
            areaNode.getChildren().add(eNode);
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

Where `AreaTreeNode` and `EquipmentTreeNode` both extend from `MipTreeNode` which is simply a serializable bean.

In my .xhtml file, I define:

```
<p:treeTable value="#{equipmentsView.root}" var="node" selectionMode="single">
    <p:column headerText="Name">
        <h:outputText value="#{node.name}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:commandLink value="edit" actionListener="#{equipmentsView.edit(node)}" />
    </p:column>
</p:treeTable>
```

So, when I click the commandLink I want to call the edit method with the current node:

```
public void edit(final MipTreeNode n) {
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

My problem is that the above method is only called for `AreaTreeNode` and not for `EquipmentTreeNode`. Did I miss anything?

Comment: _"Did I miss anything?"_ You missed at least version info... And what did you debug? There is a lot to investigate between the click on the button and the actual method call (network traffic etc)

Comment: Any progress here?

Comment: p:treeTable does not support drag and drop

Comment: Ok, that's a different story. Anyhow, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

The `p:treeTable` has two very similar attributes. And the docs are not that clear about the difference:

> **var** Name of the request-scoped variable used to
>   refer each treenode.
>
> **nodeVar** Name of the request-scoped variable that'll be
>   used to refer current treenode using EL.

In my experience with PrimeFaces 5.3 `var` refers to the data model object recievable via `TreeNode.getData()` and `nodeVar` refers to the actual `TreeNode` instance. Maybe you can use the latter and unwrap your bean in your edit method?